# How to Prevent org-global-cycle Glitch

Tags: org-mode

I'm having an issue when using `(org-global-cycle)` from a subheading followed by `(org-cycle)`.

For example in the following org file:

```
* Level 1 Heading 1
** Level 2 Heading 1
** Level 2 Heading 2
*** Level 3 Heading 1
    Test
```

If the cursor is at `*** Level 3 Heading 1{cursor here}` and I hit `S-<TAB>` everything will fold up to `* Level 1 Heading 1{cursor here}...` properly.  But the if I use `<TAB>` to view the level 2 headings I instead get:

```
* Level 1 Heading 1...
*** Level 3 Heading 1{cursor here}
    Test
```

Any clue what's going on?  I'm running `emacs.exe -q` with Emacs 24.5.1 and org-mode 8.2.10 when I use -q and 8.3.6 when running with my config.

Comment: Maybe you should fill a bug report so that it is corrected, rather than searching how to get around it (which does not solve the problem for others)?

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you what's going on, but it is not clear to me whether we should call it a bug or glitch.
When you get the position of the cursor in the unfolded document (using `(point)`) you get 84. Now, when you use the global folding and everything folds to the first headline, your cursor may seem to be positioned at `* Level 1 Heading 1{cursor here}`, but you can test that the buffer position is still 84. So, the cursor is still positioned at the end of the level 3 headline. When you do an `(org-cycle), it just opens the contents under that headline (and the headline itself).

To prevent this behavior, you need to execute any action which has an influence on the cursor. E.g. moving it one space. Even executing the `(point)` statement to get the position will end up placing the cursor in the visible region, so the first execution in the above setup will return 84, the second invocation 20.

Comment: Thanks for the response, very helpful.  I would say it's a bug because I can't think of any situation where that would be the desirable behavior, however I could certainly be overlooking something.

I wrote a function that just calls `(point)` and calling that first does solve the problem. Is there a way to call this every time `(org-cycle)` is called? Or maybe is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: I think this is definitely a bug, and I think it's one I've experienced for a long time but haven't been able to put my finger on as you have.  Maybe we should bring it up on the mailing list.

Comment: @blujay I'm all for this but don't really have any experience working with the mailing list.  If someone else is more comfortable submitting it (or pointing to some guidelines on how I can submit it) I'd be very appreciative.

Comment: Here's a thread discussing it: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2016-09/msg00386.html